# Compare two audio files in android

Tags: android, audio, compare, voice

I'm making an android app in Eclipse and i want to record my voice, which will be password for login into application. When i try to log in it should recognize my password and let me use the application. How can i do that comparison in order to get a match, i need something like shazam? Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

Audio comparisons is a very complex topic. Generally, if you don't know anything about it, I'd discourage you to head into such a project.

The problem is, that while you could of course just compare the two audio files byte by byte, that certainly is not what you want. Although two audio files *sound* the same, i.e. it contains the same spoken words, the actual data will differ quite a bit.

You'd have the following possibilities:

1. Try to recognize what the user said (Speech recognition), and check whether the same word was recognized later. This solution, while being the simplest, could not distinguish between different users.
2. Dive into the mysterious world of audio processing. A technology called Fast Fourier Transformation is more specifically what you'll be ending up dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you help me a bit with that FFT how and where can i begin.I would like to try that and if i fail ill make it like you said voice to text. Thats what i though at first.Its a college project, im not making an app for selling so i hope it will be good enough.

Comment: Where you begin?  By getting access to an academic library and reading a huge number of papers.  If you haven't studied pure mathematics and statistics at undergrad level on a physics, engineering or mathematics degree, this is probably a pre-requisite too.